# A modern n-layer asp.net web application sample?

Tags: asp.net, architecture, project, sample, n-layer

So my asp.net is very very rusty, and i'm trying to get back into best practices and what not.  So, I whip out google and start looking for examples and samples and tutorials, but what do I find?  Old crusty stuff that tends to be written even before "the latest" technology was released back in the stone age.

Sure, the concepts may still hold up.  But the actual implementations are basically useless.  I'm looking for something using Linq, n-layers (not tiers.  Tiers can be a layer, but a layer is not necessarily a tier) some kind of current ORM (L2S, EF, etc..) and some real-world stuff, not abitrary and useless examples.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: This is a good question, and some more recent questions were closed and pointed back to this, unfortunately the answers are mostly quite generic and lack much detail. So does anyone have any pointers to an up-to-date comprehensive asp.net webforms example that follows best practices. I know MVC is perceived as better, but some clients are still asking for webforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are 3 links from Daniel Simmons that should get you started:
[N-Tier Application Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee321569.aspx)
[Anti-Patterns To Avoid In N-Tier Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882522.aspx)
[Building N-Tier Apps with EF4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335715.aspx)
Also have a look at [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/), if you're interested in ASP.NET MVC (i've been working in ASP.NET for the past two years and i was a bit reluctant at first to learn ASP.NET MVC, i thought i knew everything i needed with webforms, but it's definitely a breath of fresh air, not to replace, but to complement WinForms). This project is developed by Scott Gurthie, so you're learning from the best if you check out that project. There's also a tutorial accompanying NerdDinner, but i didn't manage to find the updated (MVC 2) tutorial.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Jeff Atwood (developer of this site), has always had positive things to say about the NerdDinner sample. It's a good place to get started.

Comment: I agree about MVC, I like it a lot, and i've been through the nerddinner stuff, but unfortunately, i'm stuck in webforms for now.

Comment: I'm 'stuck' with webforms too at my day job, but that doesn't mean i can't get to try it out in my spare time. And as i've seen pointed out more than once while reading about MVC, it shouldn't be looked at as a replacement to WebForms (at least not yet, although my guess is that if ever the two are going to merge, it's MVC that's going to absorb WebForms and not the other way round). So each flavor of ASP.NET has its ups and downs, but MVC is definitely worth a try for any web developer.
Also, don't you just love the Razor syntax?

Comment: NerdDinner latest release (May 25, 2010) is more than 4 years older. Any other upto date sample?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest NSK, on codeplex:

http://nsk.codeplex.com/

It's a layered sample application based on Northwind.

Comment: This example uses asp.net mvc not webforms !

Answer (score 1):

This series of articles is very good and modern. 5 years ago we based our project on its previous version and never regretted.
http://imar.spaanjaars.com/573/aspnet-n-layered-applications-introduction-part-1

Answer (score 0):

I did some blog posts a while ago taking about this, this is a basic overview [value of n-tier design](http://bob-the-janitor.blogspot.com/2009/03/value-of-n-tier-design.html) and then I did a followup postings with a little more detail starting with [n-tier design revisit part 1: overview](http://bob-the-janitor.blogspot.com/2009/07/n-tier-design-revisit-part-1-over-view.html) a long with it I have some source code to show you what's going on

Comment: I concede those blog posts might be of some use, but they are very brief, and don't really address the original question of a real-world asp.net example !!!

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of websites out there but it's difficult to narrow them down. Try CodePlex & CodeProject for a start. There's tons of samples, categorized & rated by the community.

[**CodePlex**](http://www.codeplex.com)

[**CodeProject**](http://www.codeproject.com)

**[SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/)**

Comment: maybe the links are considered a bit generic

Comment: You're not answering the question.  I'm looking for specific samples.  I've already spent weeks scrounging those sites and frankly, it's a needle in a haystack.

Comment: @Mystere Man - have you tried this already?
http://multitierlinqtosql.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=code%20overview&referringTitle=Home

Comment: I don't think it was difficult to narrow it down to some samples, you didn't have to enumerate all of them. Of course there are a lot of good apps built around n-tier architectures, but just pointing someone out to a few source-code libraries is imho second-worst to linking google as a response.